Auto keying Grease Pencil strokes
I want to use Auto Keying for Grease Pencil so I can record an organic handwriting animation. I know that you can use Build Modifier but I it is too consistent with the timing in writing. I want a more organic write style animation equivalent to as if I was recording a video while I hand write something on my tablet. Is this possible?
I can autokey when moving an object as seen below but for Grease Pencil it only creates one keyframe on click but no subsequent keyframes for the rest of the stroke. Any ideas how I can achieve organic handwriting animation exactly as I write it without using Build modifier? Is screen recording the only way to get it exactly the way as I draw it?


In 4.3.0 the Build modifier has a new algorithm named "Natural Drawing Speed", which allows exactly what you need.
It's also possible to multiply the original speed, or use percentage with manual keyframing, to manually program any kind of needed timing.


oh wow I didn't notice this option and it does draw it at exactly the speed i was drawing at. That's interesting.. how does it remember how fast i drew?

@MeganLove Since processors can clock basically every operation, and each movement you do is an operation performed by a processor, I would guess in the new version the timing of creating the stroke is somewhere stored together with all the other data which gives the stroke its appearance, so that it can read this timing information if needed. But that is just an assumption, not that I know it. But since Blender already has to store where you were moving it seems plausible to me. You can see that it doesn't use frames but real time when changing the FPS in the scene and starting again.

@GordonBrinkmann makes sense! thank you for sharing
